# Understand WPF Window Events

Tags: c#, wpf, events

I see Windows have a `Loaded` event, but not a `Loading` event (as there is `Closing` and `Closed` events).

My expectation was that the `Loaded` event would occur before the window is actually displayed. However, looking at the [Window Lifetime Events](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms748948(v=vs.110).aspx), it shows that the `Loaded` event occurs after `Activated` event.

I put some initialization code in the `Loaded` event and there is a delay after the window is displayed and before my content appears. So what is the best event handler to use for window initialization that should occur before the window is displayed?

Comment: Is there something precluding your initializing the window content from the constructor?

Comment: @interstellarshadow: I need to access elements of the window, such as controls. I would not expect to be available from the constructor. I assume that is the main reason we have events such as the `Loaded` event.

Comment: The best method to use for window initialization that should occur before the window is displayed is to set the window's `DataContext` in the window's constructor, and let the controls populate themselves via bindings, templates, etc. Anything else is a kludge.

Comment: Isn't `ContentRendered` event fired before `Loaded` event?

Comment: If you're accessing actual controls during the load, then there is probably a more elegant way to do this. Have a look into the MVVM (Model-View-ViewModel) pattern.

Answer (score 2):

You can override `OnStartup()` in App.xaml.cs, and do stuff before calling `base.OnStartup(e);`. I just checked and this is fired before the window's constructor.

Alternatively, set the window's visibility to Hidden in its xaml file, do your initialization in the constructor and then set the visibility to Visible once done. This won't remove the delay, but the delay is only caused by whatever your initialization code is doing, so it's unavoidable unless you go asynchronous.

Answer (score -1):

Here's a simplified version of what I do (error handling removed). If the initialization takes a while, you may want to display a splash screen while you're doing your thing.

App.xaml:

```
<Application x:Class="MyProgram.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             Startup="App_StartUp" >
</Application>
```

App.xaml.cs:

```
namespace MyProgram
{
    public partial class App : Application
    {
        private void App_StartUp(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
        {
            // Create the model and MainWindow
            MyModel model = CreateModel();
            MainViewModel viewModel = new MainViewModel(model);
            MainWindow = new MainWindow(viewModel); // Sets the DataContext

            // Do things, like initialize your model
            model.Initialize();

            // Now show your window
            MainWindow.Show();
        }
    }
}
```