# WPF Can I set width for DataGrid Column before it have load by xaml?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I have a empty DataGrid (no column, no row), I can set width for it's column when data have loaded by:

```
DataGrid.Columns[3].MinWidth = 120;
```

Can I set width for a column before it have load in xaml?

Comment: Do you want the width to be set in code-behind or XAML?

Comment: To set MinWidth before. you can check events on wpf. window and understand where it falls and place it accordingly.  [Here a Good link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37974502/understand-wpf-window-events/37975171)

Answer (score 0):

In XAML: You can set it through following.

```
  <DataGrid ....... >
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn MinWidth="100" Width="200" Header="Column 1" />
        <DataGridTextColumn MinWidth="200" Width="250" Header="Column 2"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
   </DataGrid>
```